# Connecting flex/php to Active Directory

Tags: php, apache-flex, active-directory

Is there a way to connect my flex web application to Active Directory, and get the logged username?

Right now we have a PHP script connected to the flex application, that gets user/pass input from the user and checks if there's such user in the AD, and that the password is correct.
I don't want to ask for user/pass, but to make the application get the domain username that connected to it, so I could use it (check if the user has access to my application and such).

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'uname';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

When your application is launched, you need to access the LDAP with the windows login credentials.

```
`AUTH_USER` request variable is the one which you have to check. 
  This will hold your Windows login username and AUTH_USER will be 
  MYDOMAINNAME\user.name
```

> The username/password I need for this,
> is that admin credentials, or any user
> on the system?

You can get the username alone, not the password... when the user logs into his window's machine, we can check his credentials using `Environment.username` in C# and in PHP we can use AUTH_USER to verify the user logged in is valid.

> Plus, do you know where can I find a
> list of variables (like auth_user) of
> which information can I get?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php

You can get a lot of information from the above link.

Comment: The username/password I need for this, is that admin credentials, or any user on the system?
Plus, do you know where can I find a list of variables (like auth_user) of which information can I get?

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean getting the user's password.. I meant to the user/password I need to enter into the $ldaprdn/$ldappass variables.
I will check what you wrote, and the the link, tomorrow.. but it seems like that's what I needed (once I'll verify it i'll accept the answer). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so it seems like it's pretty much what we did use, and it's not exactly what we need.. but that's the best we can get of it.
What I wanted to do, is get this information without asking the user for he's user/password. Well, that's the close as I can get. Thanks for the help!